# Apache 301 redirect only for domains, not pages

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a 301 redirect to set up for my domain (`http://old-site.com` and `http://www.old-site.com`).

I would like to redirect only if nothing appears after the domain in URL.

`http://old-site.com` redirect to `http://www.new-site.com`

`http://www.old-site.com` redirect to `http://www.new-site.com`

`http://old-site.com/article/article-1.php` DO NOT redirect

I have tried this but it always redirect, even if I directly call an article:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old-site\.com    
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.new-site.com/ [R=301]
```

It should be easy to set up, but I am a real newbe in this.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Of course it redirects everything, because you matched “everything” with `(.*)`. Try matching for “nothing” instead, with just `^$`

Comment: That's it. It works as I expected. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it redirects everything, because you matched “everything” with `(.*)`.

Try matching for “nothing” instead, with just `^$`.